# For an odd degree node .

Tags: graph-theory

Let $v$ be an odd degree node. Consider the longest walk starting at $v$ that does not repeat any edges (though it may omit some). Let $w$ be the final node of the walk .
Show that $v$ $\neq$ $w$.

**My approach** :By well ordering principal,consider a walk $S$ of minimal length.
By contradiction let $v$ $=$ $w$. Removing an edge $e$ from the end-point gives a shorter walk.
This contradicts our assumption of minimality .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't follow your argument at all. You seem to be proving that a *shortest* walk cannot begin and end at the same node (which is at least doubtful -- how about the empty walk?), but the question was about a *longest* one.

Instead, if the walk both begins and ends at $v$, then the walk have used an *even* number of edges that touch $v$ -- namely, you *leave* $v$ the same number of times you *come back* to it. Since $v$ had odd degree, this means there must be at least one edge left unused that you could continue the walk along -- so it certainly wasn't the *longest* walk that doesn't repeat edges.

Comment: Indeed the question is about the longest walk, when i stated shortest walk , i am refering to the the shortest walk that can exist in this particular longest walk to which i applied the well ordering principle.

Comment: As for your proof,  am in full agreement.